# webpack not copying static html to build folder

Tags: node.js, webpack

i hava webpack.config.js file. when i run command it build perfectly but it do not copy html file in build folder.
I have html file in client/app.html. Any help will be appreciated.

```
var webpack = require('webpack'),
      path = require('path');

    function root(args) {
      args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
      return path.join.apply(path, [__dirname].concat(args));
    }

    module.exports = {
      devtool: 'source-map',
      debug: true,
      entry: './client/boot.ts',
      resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js']
      },
      output: {
        path: './build',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
      },
      module: {
        preLoaders: [
          { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'source-map-loader', exclude: [ root('node_modules/rxjs'), root('node_modules/@ngrx') ] }
        ],
        loaders: [
          { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader', exclude: [ /\.(spec|e2e)\.ts$/ ] },
          { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'raw' }
        ]
      },
      devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true
      }
    };
```

Comment: Are you referencing your app.html file in your TypeScript code? The raw loader takes the contents of the referenced file and assigns it to the variable where you're requiring/importing. It does not copy the file to the output path. If you don't want to reference the file, you could use something like [Copy Webpack Plugin](https://github.com/kevlened/copy-webpack-plugin) to copy it.

Comment: I am just giving templateUrl that points to html file. i will try Copy webpack plugin. Thanks